# Uploding Large File using OneDrive API Only Upload Portion of File

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive, dotnet-httpclient

I'm using [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession?view=odsp-graph-online#upload-bytes-to-the-upload-session) here to upload a large file to OneDrive.

After creating upload session, I try to upload to `UploadUrl` returned from this `POST` request using bellow code:

```
using (var uploadHttp = new HttpClient())
{
 SetAuthHeader(uploadHttp);

 int totalFileSize = (int)uploadStream.Length;
 int chunkSize = 327680;
 int chunkNumber =  totalFileSize / chunkSize;
 int chunkLeftover = totalFileSize - chunkSize * chunkNumber;

 if (totalFileSize < chunkSize)
    chunkSize = totalFileSize;

 var bytesData = new byte[chunkSize];

 int i = 0;

 int startIndex = 0;
 int endIndex = 0;

 int read = 0;

 while (true)
 {
    startIndex = i * chunkSize;
    endIndex = startIndex + chunkSize;

    read = await uploadStream.ReadAsync(bytesData, 0, chunkSize);
    if (read <= 0)
        break;

    if (i == chunkNumber)
        endIndex = startIndex + chunkLeftover;

    uploadHttp.DefaultRequestHeaders
     .TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length", chunkSize.ToString());
    uploadHttp.DefaultRequestHeaders
     .TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Range", $"bytes={startIndex}-{endIndex-1}/{totalFileSize}");

    response = await uploadHttp.PutAsync(uploadResponse.UploadUrl, new ByteArrayContent(bytesData));

    i++;
 }
}
```

These code run without errors, but the file uploaded to `OneDrive` is size same with `chunkSize` which in this code is `327680`.

It's seems every chunk uploaded override last upload.
Anyone know the correct code to upload large file in `OneDrive` API?

**UPDATES:**
I found my mistake in my code, instead of setting `Content-Length` and `Content-Range` in `Header`:

```
 uploadHttp.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Length", chunkSize.ToString());
 uploadHttp.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Content-Range", $"bytes={startIndex}-{endIndex-1}/{totalFileSize}");
```

It need to set it in `Content`:

```
uploadHttp.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Length", totalByteRead.ToString());
uploadHttp.Content.Headers.Add("Content-Range", $"bytes {startIndex}-{endIndex - 1}/{totalFileSize}");
```

Comment: Maybe your httpclient or function is timing out before the file finished uploading look into increasing the time of the httpclient call

Comment: I don't know the onedrive API but what's the purpose of this chunk? {startIndex}-{endIndex-1}/{totalFileSize}. Seems with operator precedence it would divide endindex first and endindex/ something larger than it as integer is always 0 so it all evaluates to startindex or am i missunderstanding?

Comment: @RonanThibaudau To tell the truth, I just doing conversion from python code example to C#, so I keep that for easy reference from original code.

Comment: @RonanThibaudau It will tell the server current upload bytes (in range value) and total size of file to upload. It's a string for and will result something like: "bytes=0-100/10000".

Comment: My bad i completelly missread while tired so didn't see if was a string interpolation and not operations on those numbers. Ignore my previous comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found error in my code (see UPDATES note on my original question).
After changing that, the upload working.